# How to kill a witch without touching it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Okay I know that's kind of self explanatory but I'll give some explanation. I'm playing minecraft and on our current world we've input a rule not to hit mobs. So weapons including bows are off limits for mobs. A bucket of lava is our main tool for killing since technically we aren't attacking it. Simply placing and picking up the lava. Witches don't take damage from lava. So I've done experimenting with dispensers and arrows with redstone and levers and it works but it is not very effective. I'm looking for an effective trap or method of killing witches without actually touching it. No weapons or fishing rods.

Comment: This is a really tough one... can you crush it or knock it down a deep hole with pistons? Hook them up to a pressure plate and lead the witch through.

Comment: Well I can but I'm looking for some type of simple trap to build possibly? Easy and quick to construct(like for example in a cave) I have to be able to build it quickly and it must fit within a small space due to cramped quarters of a cave.

Comment: Last time I played I was able to place pressure plates on TNT. Apparently that's changed. I'll do some research and get back to you ASAP

Comment: So far I've simply been running past. And it's been a good answer so far. But I'm looking to be able to be prepared for any situation I'm put into and not have to hit the mobs. I've constructed traps for every creature but a witch. And I can't seem to lure a witch through doors with pressure plates. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Would TNT a lever and red stone be okay?

Answer (score 7):

Dig a hole, any depth you want. Put at least two pistons on the side, with a block attached to each of them ; build a mecanism to activate them both.

Lure the witch to make her fall in the hole ; crush her.

---

This can even be done very fast if needed : when in a pinch, first make here fall in a 1x1 wall, cover it so she doesn't throw potions, and you just have to dig again and put your pistons to crush her.

---

**Or just use gravel/sand.**

Comment: I'd provide schematics, but I'm at work at the moment.

Comment: Ehm, guys... Given a hole with a mob to be suffocated... Why resort to pistons if you have gravel?

Comment: Oh, right. I forgot.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Witches' tactics against them: make instant damage potions and throw 'em!

Comment: @Ben - It actually does answer the question - The question OP isn't allowed to use swords/bows, however there's no restrictions on splash potions :)

Comment: This probably won't work, as witches are capable of healing and take greatly reduced damage from potions.

Answer (score 0):

Just Make A shield and whenever a witch throws a potion at you deflect it towards herself. that ways you dont waste any resources on her (almost).

Answer (score 0):

Dig a 2 block hole, push the witch inside, and crush it with a piston.

Answer (score 0):

-You can build a tower high enough for fall damage to kill a mob and then use a fishing rod to yank mobs up to you and watch them fall to their death.

-You can make a cheap slime block piston launcher to toss mobs into a pool of lava or a pit.

-You can do the classic piston mob crusher. (I´ve had problems where mobs would walk through blocks and escape before though)

-You can use a tnt duplicator glitch and blow up mobs using an obsidian floor.

Hope this helps add more weapons to your arsenal.